# Can't find the process after invoking this Perl script in shell

Tags: perl

`t`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

exec("perl -Ilib -d" . $ARGV[0]);
```

It's invoked as `t perl_script`.

But after that I can't find it by `ps`,and can't terminate it by **^C**

What's wrong ?

Comment: Why not just run `perl -Ilib -d perl_script` directly, instead of going through this strange procedure?

Answer (score 0):

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html

You're exec'ing `perl` with the args and `perl_script` you pass in. This means the current script `t` ceases to exist and is replaced by `perl -Ilib -dperl_script`.

The process you're looking for with `ps` will be the one you passed in (`perl_script`)

**Edit for comment from OP below:**

The actual process is `perl` since that's what you exec'd, but you can certainly find it via the `perl_script` you passed in using `grep`:

```
$ ps -ef |grep perl_script
broach   13039  2264  0 01:08 pts/0    00:00:00 perl -Ilib -dperl_script
```

Comment: No, you can't find `perl_script` from ps if you try, as I'm debugging that file, not running it directly.

Comment: I certainly can on my machine ... `$ ps -ef |grep perl_script` ... 
`broach   13039  2264  0 01:08 pts/0    00:00:00 perl -Ilib -dperl_script`

Comment: Though I should make my answer a little clearer, sorry - you're actually exec'ing perl

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to include a space after `-d`? Otherwise you are exec'ing

```
perl -Ilib -dperl_script
```

instead of

```
perl -Ilib -d perl_script
```

Cleaner still:

```
exec("perl","-Ilib","-d",$ARGV[0]);
exec($^X, "-Ilib", "-d", $ARGV[0]);
```